# This ring with this metric can have just isosceles triangles

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm trying to solve item (II) of this question:

[image]

[image]

**MY ATTEMPT**

Suppose $\rho(a,b)=2^{-m}$ and $\rho(a,c)=2^{-n}$ with $n\leq m$. Therefore, $a-b\in I^m\setminus I^{m+1}$ and $a-c\in I^n\setminus I^{n+1}$, then $b-c\in I^n$ and $\rho (b,c)\leq 2^{-n}$. I couldn't prove the converse, I need help in this part.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Might as well make it $n<m$ rather than $n\leq m$, since you are assume they are not equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Note that you’ve shown that if $\rho(a,b)\ne\rho(a,c)$, then $\rho(b,c)\le\max\{\rho(a,b),\rho(a,c)\}$. Now suppose that $\rho(b,c)<2^{-n}$; if $\rho(b,c)\ne\rho(a,b)$, then $\rho(a,c)\le\max\{\rho(b,c),\rho(a,b)\}$ by what you’ve already proved.